# Can I seamlessly switch my hard drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

So I got a SSD and a standard HDD in my laptop. I put the SSD myself, instead of the CD thingy. It was working fine for a while, but now the computer sometimes freezes and I strongly suspect that the SSD moves a little and thus disconnects for a bit. Can I switch spots between it and the other disc without problems? I guess my question is, has the port in which it's plugged any influence on how windows recognises a drive? Thanks

Comment: Its possible, but it can as easily be something completely different. Computer freezes is not uncommon. I would try to rule out other possibilities first, such as driver conflicts, malware, etc.

Comment: That's fair, I should have been more precise. It's not an usual freeze: some things keep working, I can move my mouse, if there's music on it keeps playing, but I can't do anything. Much like if my screen was a fixed image. And after I force shut it down and restart it, sometimes I get a blue screen with a device missing message. If I push a bit on the outside of where the SSD is (which would push it onto the port) and restart, it then works. So as I said, I strongly suspect that it's the problem.

Comment: Ah, yeah that changes everything. Sounds more likely now. We usually put a door stopper (small rubber strip with sticky coating) on the ssd to stop it from moving around.

Comment: Hmm do you think it would be better than switching it with the HDD?

Comment: I think it is going to be easier to properly secure it, than to switch it and mess with the boot settings.

Comment: I'll check. I'm not sure I'd have to mess with the boot settings though; doesn't the booter use the first bootable device in the list? So even if my SSD is after my HDD in the list, since the latter is not bootable, it shouldn't be considered should it?

Comment: I doubt you will have to change the boot order as suggested in the answer. But I do think you will get in problems with windows not finding the boot partition because its linked to a sata port etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should be no issue. You might have to adjust the boot order in your PC's BIOS assuming you have Windows installed on your SSD.

Comment: Bootorder has nothing to do with his question. He mentions he can use the SSD fine, but sometimes have instability issues.

Comment: Yes, but then he asks about switching places with his secondary HDD in order to get a better connection for his SSD. Doing that, he might has to adjust the boot order in his BIOS or else it won't boot anymore since he probably has Windows installed on his SSD.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were replying to the freezes.

Comment: I'm sorry but what @LPChip is saying is rubbish. How could Windows display an error message for not finding the boot partition when it can't even boot? It just doesn't make sense. Windows also doesn't link itself to a SATA port. When using an OEM license for example, Windows will lock to the mainboard of your computer and you can't use the license on any other computer from that point. This is, afaik, the only time Windows links itself to hardware parts.

Comment: Having to rearrange the boot order is much more likely. The BIOS should select a bootable device automatically but I've seen PCs where this was not the case.

Comment: I'm referring to the infamous "INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE" error which can happen if the bootloader tries to boot from device 0/1 while the harddisk is now attached to device 1/1.